# Monthly tracker in java

Tags: java, performance, date

I am working on a Java assignment where in I am given some raw data like below

```
   Date     Name   Sale  Discount  Product
2021-02-01   LV    143     14       P1
2021-02-18   PS    473     25       P2
2021-02-01   LV    65      5        P3
2021-02-22   XB    143     14       P1
2021-02-27   PS    143     14       P1
2021-03-03   LV    263     46       P3
2021-03-16   XB    765     38       P2
```

I need to track monthly Sales and discount provided, Also need to keep track of every 3rd P1 product sold, need to apply some logic on every 3rd P1 transaction a month. What would be the best way achieve the above using Java?

I am thinking of using HashMap with year and month as a key(eg:-202103, 202102) and creating an object which holds the required data. Please let me know if the approach is fine or it can be implemented in a better way.

Comment: You tagged this as "performance", but that should usually be your last concern in these kinds of assignments. Make it clean & usable first and *if and only if* you find out that it's too slow (which is very unlikely with these kinds of data sets) can you work towards optimizing it. Yes, I know you probably want to "learn about performance", but clean & readable code is much more important. What you've not told is how you *get* that data. You said you need to "track" it. What does that mean?

Comment: Hi @JoachimSauer, thanks for the input I wanted to find the best possible solution, that's why I have used the performance tag. By tracking I mean monthly audit data like Sales and discounts provided in a particular month. I hope it answers your query, do let me know if any further info is required from my side.

Comment: Don't focus on "best possible", that's an impossible goal and also incredibly ill-defined. What is best? Least memory used? Least CPU time? Most repsonsive? Most beautiful UI? Most buzzwordy-implementation? Sleakest micro-service architecture? Or fully testable? There is barely ever a "best possible" for all possible ways to judge "best", there's always compromises.

Comment: Roger that @JoachimSauer, I know there will be always some compromises, by best solution here I meant if there is any better solution available other than the one I was moving forward(HashMap here).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### You are thinking in the right direction.

Along with `Map`, you can make use of the [modern Date-Time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-Date-Time.html) and the `Stream` API.

You can define your data class something like

```
class Transaction {
    LocalDate date;
    String name;
    int sale;
    int discount;
    String product;
    YearMonth tranYearMon;

    public Transaction(LocalDate date, String name, int sale, int discount, String product) {
        this.date = date;
        this.name = name;
        this.sale = sale;
        this.discount = discount;
        this.product = product;
        this.tranYearMon = YearMonth.of(date.getYear(), date.getMonth());
    }

    // Getters, setters, toString etc.
}
```

Now, in the processing class, you can group the data like

```
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.YearMonth;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Transaction> list = List.of(
                    new Transaction(LocalDate.parse("2021-02-01"), "LV", 143, 14, "P1"),
                    new Transaction(LocalDate.parse("2021-02-18"), "LV", 143, 14, "P1"),
                    new Transaction(LocalDate.parse("2021-02-01"), "LV", 143, 14, "P1"),
                    new Transaction(LocalDate.parse("2021-02-22"), "LV", 143, 14, "P1"),
                    new Transaction(LocalDate.parse("2021-02-27"), "LV", 143, 14, "P1"),
                    new Transaction(LocalDate.parse("2021-03-03"), "LV", 143, 14, "P1"),
                    new Transaction(LocalDate.parse("2021-03-16"), "LV", 143, 14, "P1")
                );
        
        Map<YearMonth, List<Transaction>> map = list.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(t ->t.getTranYearMon()));
        System.out.println(map);
    }
}
```

You can dop the rest of processing as per your business logic.

Learn more about the modern Date-Time API from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

Learn more about the `Stream` API from [Processing Data with Java SE 8 Streams, Part 1](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/ma14-java-se-8-streams.html) and [Part 2: Processing Data with Java SE 8 Streams](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/architect-streams-pt2.html).