# Given a list of times, how to group them in such a way that close times are in the same group and distant ones are not?

Tags: java, algorithm, time, grouping, zoneddatetime

Suppose I have a list of timestamps with the same date of the type `ZonedDateTime`.
Instead of printing them out, I'd like to be able to group them in some say, and just print intervals e.g

```
07:41:05 - 07:55:46
08:21:35 - 08:45:42  //first being the first elem of the group, second being the last
etc
```

I was just thinking about converting them all to milliseconds first, then sorting the timestamps, and maybe choose a value like 100000 milliseconds as a separator, so if two timestamp millisecond values are less than 100000 milliseconds apart, i consider them as part of the same group.

In worst case all timestamps are in this distance apart when sorted, and then I have a huge group where the start and end elements of the interval are hours apart, but i hope that's not likely to happen with the given dataset.

Is there a better way to do this?
The question is not answered yet.

Comment: Your question is unclear. Do you want hopping/sliding/non-overlapping windows? Or do you have a certain point in time or timestamp and want all timestamps that are at most `x` milliseconds away?

Comment: Your question is not clear to me. Maybe something like https://stackoverflow.com/q/68234308/10819573 can help you progress.

Comment: @Turing85 is it not related to overlapping. It's just a set of timestamps, and instead of just printing them out in a sorted way, I was told to group them somehow, so that if there are timestamps that differ only with a couple minutes and such, they are grouped together, i.e only one is shown instead of both, or the interval notation `a-b`

Comment: @josejuan  the timestamps all refer to the same day, only the time is different. what do you mean with list by hour. what if there is one stamp at `07:59` and the other one in `08:01` I want them to be grouped together and not shown in two different groups.

Comment: @sdsfsdfsdf: so 7:59 and 8:01 should be grouped together, but 8:01 and 8:11 should not be grouped? Are you asking how to get the difference between two timestamps and if it is larger than an (arbitrary) threshold, start a new group? What happens if new timestamps are inserted; will existing groups suddenly be merged (because their difference is now too small)?

Comment: @knittl it is assumed the data won't change during execution.

Comment: @josejuan well that was the question, what would be the best grouping criteria, to avoid two timestamps that are too close to be in different groups. I guess the grouping criteria would be the difference between two timestamps. so if that is within a certain threshold, we group them together. unless you got a better suggestion of course.

Comment: ah, then you are looking for k-means et.al (without any optimization function infinite solutions exists) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-means_clustering

Comment: I updated my solution using k-means.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using k-means:

```
// sample data
List<ZonedDateTime> xs = IntStream.range(0, 10).mapToObj(n ->
        ZonedDateTime.now().truncatedTo(ChronoUnit.DAYS)
                .plus(ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(0, 24 * 60), ChronoUnit.MINUTES))
        .collect(toList());

// assume xs is not empty
ZonedDateTime day = xs.get(0).truncatedTo(ChronoUnit.DAYS);

final int WINDOWS = 3;

System.out.printf("== fixed windows (millis precision) using k-means%n");
Map<Double, List<ZonedDateTime>> points = xs.stream()
        .collect(groupingBy(x -> (double) ((x.toInstant().toEpochMilli() - day.toInstant().toEpochMilli()) / 1000), toList()));
Double[] keys = points.keySet().stream().sorted().toArray(Double[]::new);
double[][] kpoints = new double[keys.length][2];
// put keys along f(x)=0 line
for (int i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
    kpoints[i][0] = keys[i];
    kpoints[i][1] = 0;
}
double[][] centroids = new double[WINDOWS][2];
for (int i = 0; i < WINDOWS; i++) {
    centroids[i][0] = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextDouble(keys[0], keys[keys.length - 1]);
    centroids[i][1] = 0;
}
final EKmeans eKmeans = new EKmeans(centroids, kpoints);
eKmeans.run();
// regroup
int[] igroup = eKmeans.getAssignments();
Map<Integer, List<ZonedDateTime>> groups =
        IntStream.range(0, igroup.length).boxed()
                .collect(groupingBy(i -> igroup[i], collectingAndThen(toList(),
                        rs -> rs.stream().flatMap(r -> points.get(keys[r]).stream()).collect(toList()))));
groups.forEach((k, rs) -> {
    System.out.printf("  - group %d%n", k);
    rs.forEach(r -> System.out.printf("   %s%n", r.format(ISO_LOCAL_TIME)));
});
```

with output

```
== fixed windows (millis precision) using k-means
  - group 0
   03:09:00
   03:22:00
   05:22:00
   05:38:00
   07:34:00
  - group 1
   16:30:00
   18:25:00
  - group 2
   11:23:00
   11:48:00
   14:07:00
```

Comment: yes I fixed the number of groups (the k value), k-means automatically construct the k closest groups (also exists ways to get the best k but as I said we need an optimization function)

Comment: hmm, seems like a much more interesting approach than what i previously had in mind. thanks. does it cover the case when there are fewer elements than groups available?

Comment: if n <= k then every element is a group

Comment: so there won't be any empty groups created? sorry for that stupid question, i'm just not that used to data science concepts or their implementation